# Filling an array with arrays or vectors in python using numpy without a loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to find a way to fill an array with rows of values. It's much easier to express my desired output with an example. Given the input of an N x M matrix, array1,

```
array1 = np.array([[2, 3, 4],
[4, 8, 3],
[7, 6, 3]])
```

I would like to output an array of arrays in which each row is an N x N consisting of the values from the respective row. The output would be

```
[[[2, 3, 4],
  [2, 3, 4],
  [2, 3, 4]],
 [[4, 8, 3],
  [4, 8, 3],
  [4, 8, 3]],
 [[7, 6, 3],
  [7, 6, 3],
  [7, 6, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape the array from 2d to 3d, then use `numpy.repeat()` along the desired axis:

```
np.repeat(array1[:, None, :], 3, axis=1)

#array([[[2, 3, 4],
#        [2, 3, 4],
#        [2, 3, 4]],

#       [[4, 8, 3],
#        [4, 8, 3],
#        [4, 8, 3]],

#       [[7, 6, 3],
#        [7, 6, 3],
#        [7, 6, 3]]])
```

Or equivalently you can use `numpy.tile`:

```
np.tile(array1[:, None, :], (1,3,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which is sometimes useful is the following

```
out = np.empty((3,3,3), dtype=array1.dtype)
out[...] = array1[:, None, :]
```